# CentOS 6.5 will not sleep after period of inactivity

Tags: centos, power-management, sleep

I've recently upgraded my `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` to `CentOS 6.5`.  This is a desktop PC (non-server) that I would like to sleep/power down after a period of inactivity.

I have the following settings in my `Power Management` section, but these are not working the PC remains fully powered on no matter how long it sits idle.  The sleep feature was working with `Ubuntu` am I missing a setting somewhere?

[image]

```
[root@spaceship ~]# lshal |grep suspen
  org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.method_execpaths =  'hal-    system-power-suspend', 'hal-system-power-suspend-hybrid', 'hal-system-power-hibernate', 'hal-system-power-shutdown', 'hal-system-power-reboot',  hal-system-power-set-power-save'} (string list)
  power_management.can_suspend = true  (bool)
  power_management.can_suspend_hybrid = false  (bool)
  power_management.can_suspend_to_disk = true  (bool)
  power_management.can_suspend_to_ram = true  (bool)
```

I've found the following commands do work to suspend, but the computer still will not suspend or hibernate with inactivity:

```
To suspend to ram:
  echo mem > /sys/power/state

To suspend to disk:
  echo disk > /sys/power/state
```